# Ranger putting oil inside the exhaust

Tags: throttle

My Ranger 2.2 Diesel 2013 model puts oil inside the exhaust and therefore discharges excessive smokes from the exhaust.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I'm not really sure what you're trying to solve here? I understand there's an issue with excessive smoke, but not sure what your question is?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the mileage, that sounds like bad piston rings, or bad valve guides.

Does it smoke more when lifting the throttle?  Does it get better as the engine warms up?

A compression test would be a good starting point.